# is "next evolution" redundant?

Tags: editing, word-choice, phrasing

Does saying "next evolution" sound redundant?  Isn't evolution already something that comes next? I'm editing an article and the author talks about the "next evolution" of a theory, where two older theories are getting merged and refined to create this new approach. To me the "next evolution" hits the ear wrong. What do you all think?

Comment: I guess it should be *the next stage in (the) evolution*... something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal here isn't to explain that there is a progression. I agree that's what evolution already entails.

The goal here is to *move the frame of conversation* to a more evolved state than what was previously being discussed. For example:

> First, we made wheels from stone. We then realized that we should build them from wood. The next evolution was so innovative that we're still using it to this very day: rubber.

"Next" is being used here to get the reader to shift their focus to the improvement that we used *after* we moved away from wooden wheels. Without it, the reader will still be in the mindset of wooden wheels, which make the end of the sentence confusing.
"Next" is a hint for the reader (who has not yet read the whole sentence) that we're not talking about wood anymore.

Pedantically, it should be "the next **stage/step of the** evolution" but I'm inclined to allow the omission here as "evolution" is informally understood to indicate the discrete steps on the path of evolution.

Comment: I like your example. Describing what is it that we are evolving from makes the phrase sound more appropriate (not beginning the paragraph with it, in my case).

Answer (score 1):

Since evolution is a process and not an event, the "next evolution" does not sound correct to anyone who can comprehend the distinction. As one such person, I believe that a more appropriate phrase would be the "next step of evolution" or "further evolution". Of course, given tendency of American English, and especially of its marketing and journalism slangs, to shorten all phrases, I am afraid that the "next evolution" is becoming a norm...

Comment: You seem to recommend the same solution as the accepted answer. What does your answer add that is new?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a clumsy phrasing, I guess because "next" is usually paired with something countable. Perhaps "further evolution" or "future evolution" would flow better.

But it's definitely not redundant, and evolution is not "something that comes next", it's a process that takes time. If we're talking biological evolution, that's been going on for some four billion years already. It makes sense to distinguish whether we're talking about evolution from now on (or from another given point on) or about the evolution that brought us to this point.

Comment: _"next is usually paired with something countable"_. The noun "evolution" has a countable form ([definition #6 here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evolution)), which refers to a discrete step on the evolutionary path. For example, on the path of evolution of A->B->C->D->E, you could say that there have been four evolutions (A to B, B to C, C to D, D to E). It's not as rigorously defined as the uncountable variant, but it's in informal use (at the very least).

Comment: Thank you! The countable bit makes sense, that might be triggering my gut reaction here.

Answer (score 0):

Next evolution is not redundant.
Both biological and product evolution occurs in discrete steps. In biology, it is specific mutations of genes that modify old functions or introduce new ones.

In products, like the car, there are also specific intentional changes. Before Henry Ford introduced the cast iron engine block, pistons and cylinders for the internal combustion engine were made from Rods in Pipes all lashed together and held in place by steel straps and bolts. This was so unreliable that cars shook themselves apart as the engine ran, and seldom traveled a mile without having to be fixed. The cast iron engine block replaced all of that at once.

The same thing applies to scientific theories. There was no gradual transition from Newton's Theory of Gravity to Einstein's General Relativity. Erase the blackboard and start over.

The same thing happened with Quantum Physics, a full blown restart.

"Next Evolution", especially in the intellectual context of theories and other human inventions, is entirely appropriate.

But I would prefer a more accurate term: the "Next **Revolution**".

Comment: I like "next revolution" ;) Interesting tidbit about the early cars. Makes me think of the old silent movies where the cars would fall apart. Now it makes more sense!